# Padding between images doesn't pad

Tags: html, css, padding

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#action-icons
{
    float:right;
}
#action-icons.img
{
    position:relative;
    top:-30px;
    padding-right:200px;
}
</style>
</head> 

<body> 
    <h1 class="edit">Some nifty title
    <span id="action-icons"> 
    <img src="foo.png" width="64" height="64" alt="" id="newsticky"/> 
    <img src="bar.png" width="60" height="60" alt="" id="trash"/> 
    </span> 
    </h1> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding:

```
#action-icons.img
{
    position:relative;
    top:-30px;
    padding-right:200px;
}
```

Might do it.

**Edit:** You have `#action-icons.img` remove the dot so it's `#action-icons img`.

The dot sets `img` up as a class, so as you have it, the HTML would look like:

```
<img src="bar.png" width="60" height="60" alt="" id="trash" class="img"/>
```

Hope it helps.

**Edit** - Here is the full working code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#action-icons
{
    float:right;
}
#action-icons img
{
    position:relative;
    top:-30px;
    margin-left:50px;
}
</style>
</head> 

<body> 
    <h1 class="edit">Some nifty title
    <span id="action-icons"> 
    <img src="foo.png" width="64" height="64" alt="" id="newsticky"/> 
    <img src="bar.png" width="60" height="60" alt="" id="trash"/> 
    </span> 
    </h1> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Heh, it turns out the inline wasn't needed, the problem was just my the selector.

Comment: Fair enough, took me a while to see the selector anyway :)

Answer (score 2):

Try `margin-right`

and use

```
#action-icons img
```

to address the image.

```
#action-icons.img
```

means "any element with the ID `action-icons` and the *class* `img`.

Comment: @ripper additionally, use `img#action-icons` instead of `#action-icons.img`. As it stands, the rule doesn't get applied.

Comment: Your answer still didn't work ... @Kyle's did the trick. Thanks for the effort.

Comment: @Pekka: Unless I'm mistaken, `img#action-icons` would match any img with the id 'action-icons', though. You want `#action-icons img` - any image that is a descendant of a node with the id 'action-icons'.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
#action-icons.img
```

To

```
#action-icons img
```

and check

it works for me on firefox